Are words marked with the "old-fashioned" tag in dictionaries suitable for academic writing?
I guess there are old-fashioned informal words, but it seems to me that most "old-fashioned" words are formal. I've seen these words in the dictionary quite often, e.g. nigh on or  nay (in the sense of "or even"), and always wonder whether I should learn them or not.
So, is it advisable to use words marked with the "old-fashioned" tag in academic writing? As a non-native speaker, I'm not exposed enough to formal writing to come to a conclusion myself. Thank you!

How does your language deal with this? It depends on many factors but this is an opinion question and therefore not really suitable for this forum.

I’m voting to close this question because it is an opinion is asked for.

I would advise learners to avoid any "risky" usages until they're confident. There's never harm in using simple, everyday language in academic writing, unless it's colloquial enough to be inappropriate. "Formal" is often misunderstood as "fancy," as if the more it is removed from everyday language the better. But really it just means "avoid slang." In fact, "nigh on" might be disqualified for that reason; I associate it with rural speech ("That there hill's nigh on to two miles off").

There's no single answer for this, because there's no single definition of what "old-fashioned" means, nor does it mean that something has fallen from use or is archaic.
"Nigh on" is old-fashioned in the sense that 'nigh' comes from Middle English and we'd say "near" in modern English - but the fact is, we've never stopped using 'nigh'. The phrase "the end is nigh" emerged in the late 19th century, became widely recognised and was used well in the 20th century, for example. And I still use and hear others using "nigh-on" to mean "almost". Beyond those recognised phrases though, we wouldn't use it in place of "near".
By contrast, your other example of "nay" is recognised, but not widely used outside of a few very specific contexts. It's something of a trope that people from Yorkshire and Lancashire used 'nay' in their dialects of English longer than most other native British English speakers, so you'll occasionally hear it in period pieces on television. It also has a historical use in UK parliament, where votes are sometimes cast either as "aye" (yes) or "nay" (no).
There are some words from older forms of English that we occasionally use for effect, such as "alas" and "perchance". We know they sound dated - using them can add humour, sarcasm, or make something sound mock-ceremonial.
But there are also some archaic words that still appear (to my surprise) in the dictionary which are not at all in common use. For example, "beldam" (a malicious old woman, apparently) is a word I had never heard until I found it a few moments ago. I can only presume that some words remain in dictionaries because they can be found in literature which is still read and studied.
So, in answer to your question of whether you should use words tagged as 'old-fashioned', I would have to say it depends. If you're writing a period piece and want to sound old-fashioned, then yes, but you'd have to do your research well to make sure the word was used in that exact time and place. If you are using contemporary language and want to use an old-fashioned or archaic word or phrase for effect then you'd also have to research well to make sure you knew how it would be understood and received.

Nae (nay) is still used extensively in Scots dialects too.

Balanced answer. Just to add... anyone using rare words sets the stage for malapropisms. Those moments look worse than never using dated language at all. Maybe learning and using are different.

I've seen beldam used, mostly in sci-fi/fantasy that is deliberately trying to sound pre-modern.  Jack Vance used it fairly often. In Neil Gaiman's Coraline, the female antagonist was named The Beldam, which would probably be the best-known recent usage of this word.

All that discussion re nay and nign on mostly refer to speech. For academic writing, are those a good examples?

@BillyKerr That's a little misleading to say. Modern English 'no' has two meanings - it means negative (as in "no, that is not correct"), and zero (as in "we have no bananas today"). The Early Modern English 'nay' was exclusively used as the opposite of 'yea' (yes). It never meant 'zero'. But the current Scots' use of 'nae' is the exact opposite - it only means zero (as in "nae bother"). I don't believe it is used to mean 'negative'.

@Astralbee - yes its meaning is different in those examples, but the meaning is a little more complex than that.  It can be a negative in the sense of no/not. It's used in that sense in various Scots dialects, especially those on the east coast (my own) and also Shetland.  An example would be "It's nae guid" = "It's not good", and also in negating verbs: isnae, wuidnae, etc.    I'm not sure if other Scots dialects might use it as a simple "No!", but wouldn't put a bet on it not existing somewhere in Scotland. There are quite a few varieties of Scots that always surprise me.

@BillyKerr Granted, but like you said, in your example it means "not". In Middle English, that was nought, which means nothing, or zero. However, the form "not" was already fully established by the Early Modern English period and so was a different word to "nay". "Nay" and "not" were not directly related in Early Modern English, so I'm still not seeing your argument that the modern Scottish "nae" is related to "nay".

@Astralbee - there are attested examples of "nae" being used as the basic "no" negation in the Scottish National Dictionary, and not from that far back, mid 20th century.

@BillyKerr Mate, those quotes are from 1828 and 1957 respectively. I thought you were making a case that modern Scottish English uses the Early Modern English 'nay'? Look - Scottish English only began to emerge as a distinct dialect of English in the early modern period. Prior to that, Scots, while sharing a common ancestry with English, was a different language. In 1828, the date of your quote, the form of Scottish English spoken would have been heavily influenced by both Scots and Southern British English. I don't know what you are trying to prove here. Is my answer wrong?

@Astralbee I never said your answer was wrong. I upvoted it! However, Scottish English is just standard English with a Scottish accent. I'm talking about the Scots language  which is still spoken and very much still alive!  The examples from 1942 (Roxburgh, in the Borders, a few miles from the English border) and 1957 (Kincardinshire, in the North East) are examples of modern Scots dialects in which "nae" is used as a simple negative "no", in the same way as "nay" in is still used in some English dialect areas.

@BillyKerr Thanks for the upvote, and for clarifying that you're not talking about English.
